# Longest subsequence such that difference between adjacents is one

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

```
    Input:
    10 9 4 5 4 8 6
    Output:
    3

NOTE: For arrays with only 1 element or if no adjacent elements in array have difference 1, print 1 as output
```

Code:

```
int longestSubSequence(int arr[],int n) {
    int local_length=1;
    int max_length=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++) {
       if(abs(arr[i]-arr[i+1])==1) {
           local_length++;
       } else {
           max_length=max_length>local_length?max_length:local_length;
        local_length=1;
           }
        }
max_length=max_length>local_length?max_length:local_length;
        return max_length;
    }

Algorithm:
1. Maintain 2 different length: local_length and max_length initialized to 1.
2. For every subsequence whose difference is 1, local_length is increased by 1.
3. When difference between adjacent elements is not 1, max_length is updated.
4. If subsequence forms at last, so max_length is updated outside the array.
```

Geeksforgeeks gives wrong answer for certain inputs. Is this algorithm correct or am i missing any corner cases ?

Answer (score 2):

The code you’ve posted seems to solve a different problem - find the length of the longest sub**array** whose elements differ by +1 or -1. That is, this code only looks for the longest range of *consecutive* elements with this property, whereas you’re looking for the largest group of elements with this property, even if they aren’t consecutive.

As a hint for how to solve your problem: scan the array from left to right. Whenever you see an element, you’ll need a quick way to look back at the earlier array elements to determine if your number can extend any existing sequences. So maintain a hash table storing the previous numbers seen and the lengths of the longest subsequences ending at those numbers, and think about how you’d update that table having seen a new number.

Comment: If we sort the array and then run subarray algorithm, that should also calculate longest subsequence with difference 1, but this approach does not work. Why ?

Comment: Consider the array `[10, 1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5]`. Here, the longest subsequence with difference 1 would be `10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5`. However, if you sort this, you get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`, and would incorrectly report a much longer sequence.